# SQL Server 2005 money format

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have been using SQL Server 2005, and I need to store some columns in database in `Money` format.

But SQL Server stores them like this --> `0000.0000`, but I only want 2 digits after the decimal point  --->  `0000.00`

Do I have to control this in the program or there is a way to change this format in SQL Server 2005 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post datatype for that column?

Comment: Stop using MONEY, use DECIMAL. Greater control over precision/scale, better accuracy when used in calculations.

Comment: If you must use MONEY you can cast it to decimal 'cast(0.12345 as decimal(5,2))' resulting in 0.12

Comment: Really Thanks, Could u tell me does money format have any advantages than decimal format ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would normally do these formatting stuffs in the front end. But if you still have to do it within the DB layer itself then make use of ROUND function.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(1234.1234, 2) AS MONEY)
```

Would also suggest you to check out the **Performance storage comparison between Money & Decimal** post written by Aaron Bertrand: https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal

**Money Vs Decimal Vs Float Decision Flowchart (Extract from SQLCAT.com):**

[image: Money vs. Decimal vs. Float Decision Flowchart Extract from SQLCat.com]
**Source:** http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/09/25/the-many-benefits-of-money-data-type.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `Round()` function. Returns a numeric value, rounded to the specified length or precision.
More [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

```
Round(value,2,1)
```

Second parameter specifies precision to be two decimal places.

Third parameter with value one specifies truncate rather than round off.

Answer (score 2):

**try this it works for SQL Server 2008 and below (2012 have already a FORMAT() function that you can use)**

this will only works for data type Money and SmallMoney

```
declare @v money -- or smallmoney
set @v = 1000.0123
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 0)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 1)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 2)
select convert(varchar(25), @v, 126)

select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 0)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 1)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 2)
select '$' + convert(varchar(25), @v, 126)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Let me correct myself FORMAT() function is only available in SQL Server 2012